# Submit a form with Mechanize and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mechanize

I'm trying to estimate the cost of the shipment from the shipping company page.

The problem is that I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

This is my approach:

```
    mechanize = Mechanize.new
page = mechanize.get('http://www.chilexpress.cl/cotizador-envios-de-encomiendas-tarifas')
origen = page.at("#ddlOrigenCotizacion")
destino = page.at("#ddlDestinoCotizacion")
producto = page.at("#ddlProductoCotizacion")
link = page.at("#btnSig")
largo = page.at("#txtLargo")
ancho = page.at("#txtAncho")
alto = page.at("#txtAlto")
peso = page.at("#txtPeso")
origen['value'] = 'AHOS'
destino['value'] = 'AHOS'
producto['value'] = '3'
largo['value'] = '5'
alto['value'] = '5'
ancho['value'] = '5'
peso['value'] = '2'
puts mechanize.click(link).uri
puts '---------'
```

But is not working, `mechanize.click(link).uri` return the same page that `page.uri`

Also I tried page.form_with(:id => 'formPrincipal') approach, but i was not able to get the form inputs.

Comment: http://docs.seattlerb.org/mechanize/Mechanize.html

Comment: You need to use the form. Set the inputs like this: `form['ctl00$ContenidoPagina$txtPeso'] = '2'`

Comment: @pguardiario but how I catch the form?

Comment: @pguardiario I tried with that input and I keep getting the actual page as output from the submit.

Comment: It sounds like it didn't like your request. Those .NET forms can be a pain to troubleshoot.

Comment: @pguardiario So... I'm screwed up